# how to use regular expression in MySQL where like and in statement in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query where  I  have to look in 3 columns from a table where I have 2 columns searched on message column and  last  column should be on like . how can I use both statements at a time.

```
SELECT   date(datetime) as dateonly ,
sum(CASE message when 'Accepted Images' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedIMG,
sum(CASE message when 'Rejected Images' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedIMG,
sum(CASE when message like '%Changed  to %'    then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG
FROM customer_1.audit_trail 
WHERE  message  like ('%Changed  to %') and message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images') 
GROUP BY (dateonly)
ORDER BY (dateonly) asc ;
```

Comment: if you have only three message types like 'Accepted Images' ,'Rejected Images' ,'%Changed  to %'  then why you are adding a where clause?. The above select columns are just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OR (and group your condition)

```
SELECT   date(datetime) as dateonly ,
sum(CASE message when 'Accepted Images' then 1 else 0 end) as AcceptedIMG,
sum(CASE message when 'Rejected Images' then 1 else 0 end) as RejectedIMG,
sum(CASE when message like '%Changed  to %'    then 1 else 0 end) as ChangeIMG
FROM customer_1.audit_trail 
WHERE  (message  like ('%Changed  to %') OR message in ('Accepted Images','Rejected Images')) 
GROUP BY (dateonly)
ORDER BY (dateonly) asc ;
```